# Como gerar código de barra como imagem e salvar em meu servidor?

Tags: php, imagem, código-de-barras

Estou criando uma *landing page* em que o usuário se cadastra e será gerado um código de barra que é enviado via e-mail ao usuário em um cupom de desconto, estou usando a biblioteca **barcode.inc.php** para gerar a imagem de código de barra, eu preciso salvar essa imagem no meu servidor para usar ao enviar o e-mail, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Esse é meu código:

```
require_once('barcode.inc.php'); 
$code_number = '125689365472365458';//125689365472365458 
new barCodeGenrator($code_number,0,'hello.gif', 190, 130, true);
```

Comment: Você pode gerar a imagem, fazer upload para uma pasta no seu servidor e salvar apenas o link da imagem no banco. Espero ter ajudado!